# Show latest posts for each subcategory in a menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm trying to do a menu made of categories and subcategories. For each subcategory, I would like to display the latest posts in this category. I have tried to create a walker with bits of code found here and there, but right now it's displaying the same latest post for each item, and it's placed between the parent categorie and its children. How could I fetch the good category, and show the latest post only for the subcategories? Here is my code:

```
 class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

 function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
  {
       global $wp_query;
       $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

       $class_names = $value = '';

       $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

       $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
       $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

       $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" ' . $value . $class_names .'>';

       $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

       $prepend = '<strong>';
       $append = '</strong>';
       $description  =  '<div id="querySort"></div>';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        //ajout du nb de posts

        $submenus = $depth == 0 ? get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'value' => $item->ID ) ) ) ) : false;

        $item_output .= $submenus ? ' <span class="submenus-count">(' . count( $submenus ) . ')</span>' : '';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );


        //add last post for each subcategories

         $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name); 
         $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category ); 

         $list_recent_cat_post = '<ul class="show-hide">';
         $args = array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'category_name' => $category->name );
         $myposts = get_posts( $args );
         foreach( $myposts as $mypost ) :  
            $list_recent_cat_post .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($mypost->ID) . '">' . $mypost->post_title . '</a></li>';
         endforeach; 
         $list_recent_cat_post .= '</ul>';



         $link = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" '; 
         if ( $use_desc_for_title == 0 || empty($category->description) ) 
             $link .= 'title="' . sprintf(__( 'View all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name) . '"'; 
         else 
             $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"'; 
         $link .= '>'; 
         $link .= $cat_name . '</a>'; 

         if ( (! empty($feed_image)) || (! empty($feed)) ) { 
             $link .= ' '; 

             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= '('; 

             $link .= '<a href="' . get_category_feed_link($category->term_id, $feed_type) . '"'; 

             if ( empty($feed) ) 
                 $alt = ' alt="' . sprintf(__( 'Feed for all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name ) . '"'; 
             else { 
                 $title = ' title="' . $feed . '"'; 
                 $alt = ' alt="' . $feed . '"'; 
                 $name = $feed; 
                 $link .= $title; 
             } 

             $link .= '>'; 

             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= $name; 
             else 
                 $link .= "<img src='$feed_image'$alt$title" . ' />'; 
             $link .= '</a>'; 
             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= ')'; 
         } 

         if ( isset($show_count) && $show_count ) 
             $link .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')'; 

         if ( isset($show_date) && $show_date ) { 
             $link .= ' ' . gmdate('Y-m-d', $category->last_update_timestamp); 
         } 


         $link .= $list_recent_cat_post;


         if ( isset($current_category) && $current_category ) 
             $_current_category = get_category( $current_category ); 

         if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) { 
             $output .= "\t<li"; 
            $class = 'cat-item cat-item-'.$category->term_id; 
             if ( isset($current_category) && $current_category && ($category->term_id == $current_category) ) 
                 $class .=  ' current-cat'; 
             elseif ( isset($_current_category) && $_current_category && ($category->term_id == $_current_category->parent) ) 
                 $class .=  ' current-cat-parent'; 
             $output .=  ' class="'.$class.'"'; 
             $output .= ">$link\n"; 
         } else { 
             $output .= "\t$link\n"; 
         } 

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your function man:

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

 function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
  {
       global $wp_query;
       $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

       $class_names = $value = '';

       $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

       $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
       $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

       $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" ' . $value . $class_names .'>';

       $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

       $prepend = '<strong>';
       $append = '</strong>';
       $description  =  '<div id="querySort"></div>';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        //ajout du nb de posts

        $submenus = $depth == 0 ? get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'value' => $item->ID ) ) ) ) : false;

        $item_output .= $submenus ? ' <span class="submenus-count">(' . count( $submenus ) . ')</span>' : '';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );


        //add last post for each subcategories

        if( $item->type == 'taxonomy' && $item->post_parent != 0 ){

             $list_recent_cat_post = '<ul class="show-hide">';
             $args = array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'category__in' => $item->object_id );
             $myposts = get_posts( $args );
             foreach( $myposts as $mypost ) :  
                $list_recent_cat_post .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($mypost->ID) . '">' . $mypost->post_title . '</a></li>';
             endforeach; 
             $list_recent_cat_post .= '</ul>';
            }else{
                $list_recent_cat_post = ''; 
            }


         $link = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" '; 
         if ( $use_desc_for_title == 0 || empty($category->description) ) 
             $link .= 'title="' . sprintf(__( 'View all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name) . '"'; 
         else 
             $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"'; 
         $link .= '>'; 
         $link .= $cat_name . '</a>'; 

         if ( (! empty($feed_image)) || (! empty($feed)) ) { 
             $link .= ' '; 

             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= '('; 

             $link .= '<a href="' . get_category_feed_link($category->term_id, $feed_type) . '"'; 

             if ( empty($feed) ) 
                 $alt = ' alt="' . sprintf(__( 'Feed for all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name ) . '"'; 
             else { 
                 $title = ' title="' . $feed . '"'; 
                 $alt = ' alt="' . $feed . '"'; 
                 $name = $feed; 
                 $link .= $title; 
             } 

             $link .= '>'; 

             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= $name; 
             else 
                 $link .= "<img src='$feed_image'$alt$title" . ' />'; 
             $link .= '</a>'; 
             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= ')'; 
         } 

         if ( isset($show_count) && $show_count ) 
             $link .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')'; 

         if ( isset($show_date) && $show_date ) { 
             $link .= ' ' . gmdate('Y-m-d', $category->last_update_timestamp); 
         } 


         $link .= $list_recent_cat_post;


         if ( isset($current_category) && $current_category ) 
             $_current_category = get_category( $current_category ); 

         if ( 'list' == $args->style ) { 
             $output .= "\t<li"; 
            $class = 'cat-item cat-item-'.$category->term_id; 
             if ( isset($current_category) && $current_category && ($category->term_id == $current_category) ) 
                 $class .=  ' current-cat'; 
             elseif ( isset($_current_category) && $_current_category && ($category->term_id == $_current_category->parent) ) 
                 $class .=  ' current-cat-parent'; 
             $output .=  ' class="'.$class.'"'; 
             $output .= ">$link\n"; 
         } else { 
             $output .= "\t$link\n"; 
         } 

    }
}
```

The problem with your function was that you hoped that variable $category is set. This is an mistake. Another one was that you did not check for menu item type. You wanted to apply submenu only for menu item of taxonomy type. And to get posts from that taxonomy, you have to get posts with category__in arg containing category ID, which you can get from $item->object_id.

Comment: Oh it's working, thank you so much!! One last thing though, it's showing the recent post also for the main categories, and I would like it to be only for the subcategories, level 2 in my menu, any idea how to get there?

Comment: I've modified the code in answer. Added **&& $item->post_parent != 0** to **if( $item->type == 'taxonomy' )** condition. Does what you need.